# On iOS, if a subclass of CALayer is used with an empty display method, then app seems to go into infinite loop?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, core-animation, calayer

If a Single View app is created, with a `FooView` that subclasses `UIView`, and do a

```
NSLog(@"hello");
```

in `drawRect`, then it is printed.

And if I create a subclass of `CALayer` called `CoolLayer`, and add this method to `FooView.m`:

```
+(Class) layerClass {
    return [CoolLayer class];
}
```

and at the end of `FooView.m`'s `drawRect`, do a

```
NSLog(@"layer's class is %@", self.layer.class);
```

then `CoolLayer` is printed.  So now the view's underlaying layer is `CoolLayer`.

But when the following is added to `CoolLayer.m`:

```
-(void) display {

}
```

which is the method that is automatically called to redraw the layer (similar to `drawRect`), then no `NSLog` whatsoever was printed.  It might be that the app went into an infinite loop. (even my `touchesBegan` that prints out NSLog messages is not printing).  If a breakpoint is set at `display`, it will stop there once but when I continue the program, it will never arrive at `display` again.  What is wrong with this and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layer's display method will not be called again unless the layer is dirty, i.e. set to need a redisplay. This is usually a good thing, and is why you don't see the method being called more than once.

Also, the normal implementation of display will call the `drawInContext:` method. Since you override this in your subclass, the `drawRect:` method of the view is never called. You need to either replicate the standard behavior of `CALayer`, or call the superclass' `display` method in your own implementation.

Comment: That's really strange: if my CoolLayer's `display` is an all empty method, those `NSLog` won't be printed out and the `touchesBegan` won't print out `NSLog` messages, but if I add `[super display];` to that empty `display` method, then all those `NSLog` messages will be printed out

Comment: Yes, this is as expected. See [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500) for info on the default behavior.

Comment: Oh which part in the doc is that?  I mean, does the doc has a statement that says, if the `contents` is not touched or if `[super display]` is not called, then it will somehow hang or not show NSLog in other methods (such as in touchesBegan in UIView)

Comment: Another update is that, if `[super display];` is removed, but a `self.contents = (id) [uiimage CGImage];` is added, then the image will be shown, and NSLog messages will be printed in FooView's `touchesBegan` method... but is touching or setting `contents` mandatory? The docs doesn't mention that it must be set....

Comment: Ok, I think I found the reason that NSLog messages in `touchesBegan` was not printed: there was nothing to touch.  Or the size probably is like a (0,0), and there is nothing touched, and touchesBegan was never called.  But I don't follow the logic that if `display` is empty, then `drawRect` is never called?  I set an NSTimer to repeat every 1 second to `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];`, and `display` is called, but `drawRect` is not

Comment: See the "discussion" paragraph of the `display` method. It states the default behavior (e.g. the behavior that you must either reimplement or otherwise replicate in a subclass), and also provides suggestions on how to implement it.

Comment: does it mention that drawRect is not called in some situation?  I searched that doc and it doesn't mention drawRect at all... Also, I am suspecting `display` does this: it can either set `contents` to a CGImage object, or, it starts a ImageContext, and pass that ImageContext to drawInContext, and then when it returns, convert that ImageContext into a CGImage, and set it to `contents`...  I hope some docs can verify this, and also, why is now drawRect not called even if an NSTimer sets the view with setNeedsDisplay?

Answer (score 2):

That does not sound like an infinite loop. If you were in an infinite loop your app would freeze, and after a few seconds the springboard app would kill it for being unresponsive.

Call setNeedsDisplay or setNeedsDisplayInRect  on your layer to make it "dirty" and require drawing again. Note that you don't want to call setNeedsDisplay any more than you have to, because it takes a lot of work to re-render the layer and push it's contents onto the screen. Only display when something has changed

Answer (score 1):

You're not seeing an infinite loop here. If you were, as Duncan points out, you'd eventually crash either due to the watchdog timer or from an infinite recursion that would be immediately obvious in the stack trace you'd see in the debugger.

If you put an NSLog into your UIView's `-drawRect:` method, then override its default layer class with your own custom CALayer that does its own drawing, your UIView's `-drawRect:` would no longer be called. Drawing would now be handled by your custom backing layer.

As described in the "[Providing CALayer Content by Subclassing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/ProvidingCALayerContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006642-SW8)" subsection of the Core Animation Programming Guide, you typically override `-display` in your CALayer if you want to somehow customize the `contents` CGImageRef for your layer. Normally, you'll be overriding `-drawInContext:` if you want to render custom Quartz drawing within your CALayer. Making your overridden `-display` method totally blank, and not writing anything to the `contents` property, is not standard behavior, so I'm not surprised that you're seeing odd results from doing that.

Based on your series of recent questions, I highly recommend you stop and spend some time reading the Core Animation Programming Guide and looking at some sample code involving CALayers before proceeding further.

Comment: I think I found the reason why it was odd: no image was set and there was nothing to touch... but before I see your answer here, I post another question that probably describes how `display` and `drawInContext` works... but not sure how it won't call `drawRect`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791025/on-ios-setneedsdisplay-really-doesnt-cause-drawrect-to-be-called-unless-cal . I think after I understand that, I have a pretty good understand of how CALayer caches the images, and how setNeedsDisplay really work and how `drawRect` is invoked